# Combining JPA specification with pagination

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a JPA specification that needs to be split up in two, but also support backend pagination. I am unsure how to accomplish this.

For example, I have Employess that can be of two types Teachers and Carers. I need to perform a filtered search (the exact search) on both and return a single unionized response, that can support pagination. Although I know how to perform the two requests, I don't know how to process the pagination when combining JPA specifications. Any hints?

```
class EmployeeEntity {
  private Long id;
  private EmployeeType type;
  private String name;

}
```

Comment: Can you provide some details related to your Pojo

Comment: @Daksharajkamal added some details but the question is more on how pagination can be handled when multiple specifications are linked. You can use whatever pojo you think of.

Comment: You can use Criteria API for handling pagination and multiple specifications

Comment: can you share what data you have and what actually output you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [JpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) or [ListPagingAndSortingRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/ListPagingAndSortingRepository.html) or [PagingAndSortingRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html) as they allow pagination and creating methods like `findAllByType(...)` may solve your problem.
Andd for combining results, you can use HQL type query to write a single query or create 2 queries to DB and put them in a single list/set before you return as result.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle Pagination with multiple specifications by using Criteria API.
Example:

```
DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(EmployeeEntity.class, "employee");
```

Now suppose you want to filter Employee by EmployeeType which is some different entity:

```
detachedCriteria.createAlias("employee.type", "employeeType");
detachedCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("employeeType.name", string (example: "Teachers")));
```

Similar way you can add more specifications, and for pagination, you can do this:

```
Integer pageNumber = (Integer.valueOf(page_number)-1) * 10;
```

and then you can pass all this data using the:

```
resultList = findByCriteria(detachedCriteria,pageNumber,page_size);
```

which will return your result based on the specification and pagination based on page_number and page_size

Comment: Also you can take some help from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-criteria-queries

Answer (score -1):

There is an easy way to provide pagination using JPA specs.

Starting from the controller, you need to allow two new parameters, like `int page` and `int size`. Let's say for your use case:

Controller:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/employees")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
EmployeePageResponse<EmployeeDto> getEmployees(EmployeeSearchCriteria criteria) {
    return employeeFilterService.searchEmployee(employeeMapper.toFilter(criteria), criteria.getPage(), criteria.getSize());
}
```

where:

```java
public class EmployeeSearchCriteria {
    private EmployeeType type;
    private int page = 0;
    private int size = 10;
}
```

the service just receives the filter you want to apply and propagates it to the repository layer.

Service:

```java
@Override
public EmployeePageResponse<EmployeeDto> searchEmployees(EmployeesFilter filter, int page, int size) {
    Specification<EmployeeEntity> spec = EmployeeSpec.filterBy(filter);
    // here we pass the pagination parameterers page and size
    Page<EmplooyeeDto> pageResult = carRepository.findAll(spec, PageRequest.of(page, size));
    return employeeMapper.toEmployeePageResponse(pageResult);
}
```

Filter (using Java 17 you can just create a record):

```java
public record EmployeesFilter(EmployeeType type) {}
```

And now comes the important part. Once you have the filter setup, apply it over the repository layer using JPA specs:

```java
public class EmployeeSpec {

    public static final String EMPLOYEE_TYPE= "employeeType";

    public static Specification<EmployeeEntity> filterBy(EmployeesFilter employeesFilter) {
        return Specification
                .where(hasType(employeesFilter.type()));
    }

    private static Specification<EmployeeEntity> hasType(EmployeeType type) {
        return ((root, query, cb) -> cb.equal(root.get(EMPLOYEE_TYPE), type));
    }
}
```

And finally, the repository

```java
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<EmployeeEntity, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<EmployeeEntity> {

    Page<EmployeeEntity> findAll(@Nullable Specification<EmployeeEntity> spec, @NonNull Pageable pageable);
}
```

I wrote a small tutorial a few months ago exactly about this topic. There you can also find some examples as well as the Github repo.

Hope you find it useful!
https://binarymindset.com/filter-your-data-the-right-way-using-jpa-specifications/